# ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor in .NET

Tags: .net, pinvoke

does anyone here have a code snippet: how do I convert SDDL to SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR in managed code? Like you usually do in c++ by calling [ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376401%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to.

[RawSecurityDescriptor Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.rawsecuritydescriptor.aspx).

[RawSecurityDescriptor Constructor (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y707fyek.aspx).

[GenericSecurityDescriptor.GetBinaryForm Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.genericsecuritydescriptor.getbinaryform.aspx).